# Discord bot for custom dictionary

Tags: discord.js

I'm preparing for a certification course that has almost 5000 terms in it's "dictionary". I want to create a discord bot that can be used to search for the definitions in the following way :

```
!define dog
```

and the output should be

```
dog : "A slang term used to refer to a low-growth, low-market-share product. See: growth-share matrix."
```

All the terms and definitions are currently in a tab-delimited text file in the following way :

```
term definition
term definition
term definition
```

How do I go about building such a bot?

Comment: Read this before asking question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
    var dictionary = ["dog", "cat", "ape"];
    var definitions = ["canine", "feline", "mammal"];
    var arrIndex = 0;
    var messageWords = message.content.toLowerCase().split(' ');

    if (messageWords[0] === `!define`) {
        if (isNaN(messageWords[1][0] / 1)) {
            arrIndex = dictionary.indexOf(dictionary.find(element => element === messageWords[1]));
            message.channel.send(`${dictionary[arrIndex]}: ${definitions[arrIndex]}`);
        };    
    };
```

I kept the dictionary and definitions separate because it makes using indexOf a lot easier.

Edit: you would have to separate the terms and definitions, as well as format them as shown above.